# close overlay except if "special" Div is clicked with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div called "MyDiv". When this div is clicked an overlay is shown with a "MyDiv_subDiv" appended. When user clicks on the overlay the view should disappear but NOT if iser clicks on "MyDiv_subDiv".

I've found a similar question here and tried it out, here is my code:

```js
var $MyDiv = $('#MyDiv');
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $MyDiv_subDiv = $('<div id="MyDiv_subDiv" class="subDiv">\n\
<div class="subDivContent">\n\
<div class="subDivContent">\n\
<p>some content</p>\n\
</div>\n\
</div>\n\
</div>');

//Add overlay
$("body").append($overlay);

//When overlay is clicked
$overlay.click(function () {
    //Hide the overlay
    $overlay.hide();
    $overlay.empty();
});

$MyDiv.click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $overlay.show();
    $overlay.append($MyDiv_subDiv);
});

$MyDiv_subDiv.click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
}

.subDiv{
    width: 400px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}

#MyDiv_subDiv{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

#MyDiv{
    width: 185px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyDiv">
Click to show MyDiv_SubDiv
</div>
```

The problem is: It only works when "MyDiv" is clicked first time. When overlay is closed and "MyDiv" is clicked second time and then click on "MyDiv_subDiv" it disappears - and it shouldn't!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I see that your example is working. Are you sure that you've got any problems?

Comment: it only works the first time as described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [jquery.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data
>   and event handlers from the child elements before removing the
>   elements themselves.
>
> If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event
>   handlers (so they can be re-added later), use .detach() instead.

So you have to use  `.detach` to keep the event.

And as `.detach` is apply on self, not on child, you have to change

`$overlay.empty();` to `$MyDiv_subDiv.detach();` or `$overlay.children().detach();`

or you can rebind the event everytime you append it to `$overlay`.

```js
var $MyDiv = $('#MyDiv');
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $MyDiv_subDiv = $('<div id="MyDiv_subDiv" class="subDiv">\n\
<div class="subDivContent">\n\
<div class="subDivContent">\n\
<p>some content</p>\n\
</div>\n\
</div>\n\
</div>');

//Add overlay
$("body").append($overlay);

//When overlay is clicked
$overlay.click(function () {
    //Hide the overlay
    $overlay.hide();
    $overlay.children().detach();
});

$MyDiv.click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $overlay.show();
    $overlay.append($MyDiv_subDiv);
});

$MyDiv_subDiv.click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
}

.subDiv{
    width: 400px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}

#MyDiv_subDiv{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

#MyDiv{
    width: 185px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyDiv">
Click to show MyDiv_SubDiv
</div>
```